# Cannot determine laravel file path

Tags: php, python, laravel

- I'm running **Laravel 4.x**
- I'm editing `/var/www/example.com/app/controllers/TestController.php`

  - route: http://example.com/test
- I have a file in `/var/www/example.com/scripts/test.py`
- Python is installed in `/usr/bin/python`

Inside, `TestController.php` I have tried to simply access the `test.py` file with:

```
file_get_contents('../../scripts/test.py');
```

and

```
exec('/usr/bin/python /scripts/test.py');
```

To see if I was even getting the correct paths... What changes to my paths to I need to make?

Comment: The PHP `cwd` is entry point always. If you need relative path, you need to use `__DIR__` or `__FILE__`. Like `__DIR__ . '/../../scripts/test.py'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a bunch of path "helper" functions provided with laravel 4. You can decide which one bests suits your case:

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers#paths

Something like the following should work (untested):

```
exec('/usr/bin/python ' . app_path() . '/scripts/test.py');
```